# How does ionic.config.js in ionic2 work

Tags: ionic2

I need to know in detail, how does the `ionic.config.js` file (in `ionic2`) work.
Can I use Grunt instead of `ionic.config.js` ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Grunt or Gulp for automating your builds.

Regarding your first question: Can you give us more details? Maybe tell us a bit more about what you are trying to achieve with the config file, or give us an overview of what tasks you want to accomplish?